# Accessing global variable in my custom module from a master

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

In a master i have a global variable called "READ_ONLY_ON_STATES" which is a dictionary

`READ_ONLY_ON_STATES = {"on_validation":[("readonly", True)]}`

This is the dictionary defined in the master.

I now want to access this dictionary on my module and add another key in that "READ_ONLY_ON_STATES" variable...

How to achive it... Tried various ways but unable to to... Can anyone help me out please

Comment: Where did you declare this variable?

Comment: Assume there is 2 custom module...  This variable is in 1st module and i want to access that variable in 2nd module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import `READ_ONLY_ON_STATES` using `odoo.addons.MODULE_NAME`. If it is declared in models directory inside `master` file, use the following:

```
from odoo.addons.MODULE_NAME.models.master import READ_ONLY_ON_STATES
```

You can find an example in [stock](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/fa58938b3e2477f0db22cc31d4f5e6b5024f478b/addons/stock/models/res_partner.py#L5) module where they import `WARNING_HELP` and `WARNING_MESSAGE` from base module.

```
from odoo.addons.base.models.res_partner import WARNING_HELP, WARNING_MESSAGE
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "in a master"?
As destripador said, you can use ir.config_parameter model to set and read variables in run-time.

If you just need a constant static variable defined in a python script inside an odoo module, you'll need to import it manually.
For example, let's suppose **READ_ONLY_ON_STATES** is defined inside my_module/models/my_model.py you'll need to import using Python import syntax.

```
from odoo.addons.my_module.models.my_model import READ_ONLY_ON_STATES   
print(READ_ONLY_ON_STATES)
```

or

```
from odoo.addons.my_module.models import my_model
print(my_model.READ_ONLY_ON_STATES)
```

Comment: Master is... You can say like its a new module and will be used as a dependancy in other module....

Comment: You should be able to access your "master module" variable using python import syntax

Comment: Can you please write the syntax please

Comment: I already did in my answer, just replace your paths in my code

Comment: thanks buddy, i cannot mark 2 answers as a correct answer so I upvoted you for that

Answer (score 0):

you can save global variables like this

```
 self.env['ir.config_parameter'].set_param('global_variable_name', self.comite.id)
```

and getting

```
    value1 = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('global_variable_name')
```

Comment: I already declared a global variable